# Is there an example of a non von Neumann algebra with this property?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

What is  an example  of a  $C^{*}$  subalgebra  $A$ of  $B(H)$ such that $A$ contains the  identity $I_{H}$ and satisfies the following properties:

1) For every $T\in A$, The  orthogonal projection $\pi_{T}$ on the  closure of $Range(T)$ belongs to $A$.

but

2)  $A$ is  not  a  Von  Neumann  Algebra.

The  question is  motivated by the fact that every  Von Neumann  algebra satisfies (1).

Comment: Perhaps the Calkin algebra $\frac{B(H)}{K(H)}$ works.

Comment: @AliBagheri  Thank you for your  comment. Well it  is  not  a Von Neumann algebra and it is not  a subalgebra of  B(H). For  H  separable, is the Calkin algebra  a  subalgebra of  $B(\tilde{H})$ where hilbert  dimensional of $\tilde{H}$  is $c$, the continum? Another question: is the property (1) in the question a C* intrinsic  property?(Independent of faithfull embedding and independent of H)?

Comment: Your welcome Ali.  As for your second question the answer is yes.  Let $x$ be an operator in $B(H)$ then $xH$ and $xx^*H$ have the same closure.   So we may just focus on positive operators. If $x$ is a positive operator then $\pi_x$ is just the weak-star limit of the sequence $x^{\frac{1}{n}}$.

Comment: @AliBagheri  why you guess that the calkin algebra works?

Comment: @AliBagheri  why this  weak star limit, independent of faithful representation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $A \subseteq B(H)$ be any AW*-algebra that is not a von Neumann algebra.  (Actually, we don't need a full AW*-algebra, see below.)

Let $t \in A$ be any operator.
By definition of AW*-algebra, every right-annihilator is generated by a projection.
In particular, the right-annihilator of the singleton set $\{t\}$ is generated by a projection $q \in A$.
That is to say: 1. for any $a \in A$, if $at = 0$ then $qa=a$ and 2. $qt=0$.  Thus $(1-q)t=t$.

Thus we have $1-q \geq \mathrm{Range}(t)$.
Conversely, $(1-\mathrm{Range}(t))t = t-\mathrm{Range}(t)t=0$ and so $q(1-\mathrm{Range}(t))=1-\mathrm{Range}(t)$.  Thus $1-\mathrm{Range}(t) \leq q$.  We conclude $\mathrm{Range}(t)=1-q \in A$.

Comment: thank you very  much for your very interesting answer. Is the property under my question, an intrinsic C* algebra property(Independent of faithful representation)?

Comment: Assume $\phi\colon A \rightarrow B$ is a $*$-isomorphism and $A$ is an AW*-algebra.  Let $S \subseteq B$ be any subset.  Let $R$ denote its right-annihilator.  It is not too hard to see $\phi^{-1} (R)$ is the right-annihilator of $\phi^{-1}(S)$.  As $A$ is an AW*-algebra, there is a projection $p$ such that $p A = \phi^{-1}(R)$. Then $\phi(p) B = R$.  Thus $R$ is generated by the projection $\phi(p)$.  The same argument shows this for left annihilators.  Thus $B$ is a AW*-algebra as well.

Comment: Thanks  again for your very interesting answer.

Comment: what is  an explicite example of  a  AW*  algebra which is not von neumann.

Comment: Is the  calkin algebra an example(as mentioned by @AliBagheri )?